# Cannot find proj.db in QGIS 3.10.3

Tags: qgis, proj, c++

I would like to program a standalone application using C++. In version 3.4 LTR, my program ran fine and I did not receive any notification when running it. However, when I compiled using the qgis library version 3.10.3 LTR, I received the following warnings:

```
proj_get_authorities_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create_from_wkt: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I solved my problem by setting the environment variable PROJ_LIB

Comment: Could you expand on how did you solve it and post it as an answer? Please include what value did you set PROJ_LIB to and where in code did you set the env var. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the `proj.db` file in `C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj`. So I solved the problem by setting environment variable `PROJ_LIB=C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj`

Comment: I've been having a similar problem to the one you encountered and solved by setting environment variable PROJ_LIB=C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj. Can I ask where did you set this .. in a bat file, in your script or right in your system env variables? Thanks